# How to extract Values from Sqllite in Yesod persistant

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am using Yesod for the first time, I tried out the scaffolded website ,with some minor changes I was able to implement googleOauth , I get back the uid from google and some userinfo ,then I save them to the sqlite database .Here is log that authenticate uses to verify ,just for reference

```
SELECT "id","ident","email","name","picture" FROM "user" WHERE "ident"=?; [PersistText "google-uid:11111111111"]
```

My User model is defined like below

```
User
    ident Text
    email Text
    name Text
    picture Text
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable
```

In a subsequent handle ,I want to query the DB using the id i received from google ,to extract the email,name and picture . I tried writing somehting like this

```
maid <- maybeAuthId
    let user = selectList [userIdent ==. maid] []
```

But it gives me the following error

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘EntityField record (Maybe UserId)’
                      with actual type ‘User -> Text’
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `maybeAuthId` can fail and you have to check for that:

```
maid <- maybeAuthId
case maid of
  Just id_ -> selectList ...
  _ -> do something in case of unaothorized user
```

And second problem is simple - you have to upperscore entity&field names when using inside Persistent functions:

```
selectList [UserIdent ==. id_] []
```

Comment: I still get couldn't match type ‘Key User’ with ‘Text’
            arising from a use of ‘UserIdent’